# How to use "both"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, determiners, predeterminers

A father comes back home from a long journey. He addresses his children complimenting the two of them for having grown up so much.
Will he say: "Look how you've grown up both of you!" or rather "Look how you've grown up THE both of you!" By the way, is it "how you've grown up" or "how you're grown up"

Comment: Oups! I guess "up" is one word too many here!

Comment: I would say *Look how grown up you both are!*

Comment: Or just *Look how you've **both grown**!* Note that ***to grow up*** usually implies ***become more mature, become adult*** (rather than ***get bigger, increase in height***, which is probably the intended nuance here), so you might want to lose the preposition.

Comment: What about: "Look how big you both are?" or "Look how big you've both got!" Which one is the more colloquial?

Comment: ... or the more relevant in family speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Father comes from Manchester he may well say 'the both of you'.  '**The** both' is a regional variation of 'both', common e.g. in the North West of England, and heard in the Morrissey song *There Is A Light That Never Goes Out*:

> And if a ten-ton truck
>   Kills the both of us
>   To die by your side
>   Well,
>   the pleasure - the privilege is mine

In formal writing or speech, avoid 'the both'.

[Bigger than the both of us](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2009/08/bigger-than-the-both-of-us.html)